# My missing LIGHT grey & white cat looks black in photos. How can I lighten his fur in order to share & print an accurate colour of his fur

Tags: printing

Please help me to get my cat back. All of the calls I have gotten were for 'found' black & white cats. Shamus is VERY light grey & white, so I need accurate flyers in order to make my search effective.  His photos all look dark, but printing makes them even darker than originals. I am tech challenged so please, if you can, keep that in mind. I tried just messing with various basic edits such as brightness, exposure, shadow, etc. to no avail. I have old photoshop on my computer, but haven't used it in years, and struggled with it at that time. Anything you can tell me will be so greatly appreciated. Even just how to lighten it, it doesn't have to be his accurate silvery grey colour. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What version of Windows do you have? Newer versions of Windows have some easy to use photo enhancement options that you could use.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this has to do with either shadows on the cat or potentially the exposure. You can increase and adjust them both using an online editor like photopea. You can probably use any online photo editor (if you don't have GIMP or Photoshop).

If you use photopea, go under **Image > Adjustments** and play with **Exposure** and **Brightness & Contrast**. That might do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

In Photoshop, goto Image > Adjustments > Shadows/Highlights
Slide Shadows/Highlights to the right.

This will brighten shadows/darkness areas.